# Can SSRS use pivot tables such like excel drag and drop

Tags: reporting-services

Can SSRS do this?Here is an example of what I mean: http://demos.devexpress.com/XtraReportsDemos/DataBinding/PivotGridAndChart.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make something like this, althought needs some work and it will have some limitations.

```
1. Make a query that will contain all dynamic data field names

2. Create as much row and column groups as the maximum the user needs (4 rows and 2 columns are good in my opinion)

3. Create a param for each row and column. Assign to it the dataset with field names. 
Eg. for row1 i created a parameter named R1

4. In each row and column the group should be =Fields(Parameters!R1.Value).value (replace R1 with your parameter's names) 

5. Set row and column groups visibility to hidden if the user selection is none
Eg. for row2 the group visibility is =Iif(Parameters!R2.Value="none",true,false)

6. You can also create a param that will allow the user to select the measure he wants to see (value, quantity etc)
```

See also: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/advanced-matrix-reporting-techniques/

This is something pivot like I made

[image]